# Why does Safari/Firefox not recognise Polymer

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm experimenting with Polymer-2/webcomponents, and completed successfully [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-2-carousel/index.html) tutorial. In addition I added a trial file, which loads & displays in Chrome (without proper nesting, though) but does not show at all in Safari (10.0.3) and Firefox (52.02), I see an `Reference error: can't find variable Polymer` all dependencies seem to be available under bower_components and when I enter `Polymer` in FF and Safari's console, Polymer seems te be defined, so it might be a timing issue? What more can be wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script>
  window.ShadyDOM = { force: true };
  </script>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
   <dom-module id="my-foo">
    <template>
      <h1>
        <slot></slot>
      </h1>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-foo' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="my-bar">
    <template>
      <i>
        <slot></slot>
      </i>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'my-bar' });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-foo>
    <my-bar>Hello world!</my-bar>
  </my-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
 <!-- Load webcomponents-loader.js to check and load any polyfills your browser needs -->
  <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but now I get a lot of errors like `A custom element with name dom-if|bind|module|selector' has already been defined`

Answer (score 0):

It works well if you move the document templates inside a separate file and `link rel=import href..` to that file.